# Angular 6 ngFor

Tags: angular

Sabem me explicar o porque a directiva ngFor está acionando duas vezes a função "gatilhoTeste" , sendo que o array chamado "items" ao qual ele está percorrendo só possui armazenado apenas 1 elemento do tipo objeto.

app.component.html

```
<h1>TESTANDO NGFOR</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>{{gatilhoTeste(item)}}</div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: any[] = [{id:'String Elemento'}]

  gatilhoTeste(item){
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot da dúvida]

Comment: Você limpou o cache do `console`?

Comment: sim, tentei com outros navegadores e acontece a mesma coisa. Se eu remover de dentro do array o elemento do tipo objeto e inserir um elemento do tipo string ele só percorre corretamente, somente uma vez.

Comment: Quantos `*ngFor` estão dentro do componente?

Comment: Esse é o único ngFor do componente, na verdade deixei ele para poder zerar todas as possibilidades de loop.. Estou começando a acreditar que possa ser ou um bug do Angular, ou um comportamento natural dele..

Comment: Por favor poste o codigo inves de imagem

Comment: printando a variável nome o que ele mostra?

Comment: @lucas Brongni, ele mostra o objeto dentro do array duas vezes.

Comment: @eduardovargas alterei o código para ficar mais simples

Comment: Creio que ele imprima pra cada vez que o DOM mude entao ele imprime uma vez e depois mais uma depois de inserir o elemento do ngFOR

Answer (score 2):

O causador desse "problema" é o `change detection` do Angular.

Esse processo tem como objetivo, em uma explanação breve, a pegar todos os seus `componentes` e renderizá-los na `visão`.

Cada vez que um ciclo de detecção é chamado, o componente em questão é recarregado completamente, atualizando tanto a `view` quanto o `model`.

Esse é um comportamento padrão, necessário para que os componentes possam manter um estado sempre atualizado.

No seu cenário, isso parece ser problemático, pois, aparenta que tem mais de um item no array. Porém, não é o caso.

Se fizermos uma `div` para mostrar todo o conteudo, ele apresenta só um:

```
<h1>TESTANDO NGFOR</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>{{item.id}}</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imprime só um elemento.

> Tá, mas por que quando faço com `console.log` ele imprime várias
>   vezes?

Pois bem, o ciclo de vida do console do navegador é completamente diferente do ciclo de vida de um componente Angular. Ambos são separados, um é de responsabilidade do navegador em si, outro da aplicação. Quando ocorre uma detecção de mudanças no componente, o navegador não sabe disso, ele só imprime o que recebe.

Portanto, como o componente é recarregado várias vezes durante esse processo, o `console.log` é consequentemente chamado várias vezes.

**Desenvolvimento X Produção**

Tem um outro ponto que é, quando executado em modo desenvolvimento, o ciclo de detecção de mudanças ocorre duas vezes para cada componente. 
Já em modo de produção, esse ciclo é chamado somente uma vez.

Se você buildar seu projeto [em modo de produção](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), ele só vai imprimir uma vez.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ts7s7a