# ngFor gerando muitas chamadas

Tags: angular, angular-6

Possuo um array que contém 40 posições. Ao fazer um ngFor utilizando esse array, crio uma série de componentes  dentro desse *ngFor. O problema é que está acabando com a performance. Debugando, e fazendo um contador dentro desse for, descobri que ele roda 600x, tendo somente 40 items.

Lendo sobre, descobri que se trata do Change detection, mas não consegui resolver. Alguém sabe como contornar esse comportamento? (não posso desligar o change detection).

No arquivo .ts

```js
  cont: number = 0;
  array: number[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    let i = 0;

    while(i < 40) {
      this.array.push(i);
      i++;
    }
  }

  contador() {
    console.log(this.cont);
    this.cont++;
  }
```

No html

```html
<div *ngFor="let numb of array">
  <!-- Imaginem aqui muitos outros componentes que executam várias funções -->
  <p>{{ contador() }}</p>
</div>
```

Observando no console, verão que o contador vai até 400.

Se redimensionarem a tela, por exemplo, ele ainda continua gerando mais 400 chamadas :o

Comment: Possível relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325996/angular-6-ngfor/326158#326158

Comment: Olá @weber bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor adicione alguns trechos de código para tornar a pergunta mais clara e para que possamos verificar se há algum problema no seu código, sugiro que leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Olá Pedro, tudo bem? Obrigado por tentar ajudar. É exatamente nesse post que sugeriu que eu descobri que o change detection que estava gerando os console.log a mais, porém não posso desativá-lo. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma técnica para contornar esse problema.

Comment: @LucasDuete, editei o post para melhor compreensão, agradeço pelas dicas do mínimo completo verificável.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece por causa do Change detection conforme já mencionado.

Cada vez que você adiciona no array, ele detecta e executa o ngFor* mais uma vez. É como se ele o código abaixo:

```
        let totalExecucao = 0;
        let array = [];

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            array.push(i);

            array.forEach(a => totalExecucao++);

            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                totalExecucao++;
            }
        }
        console.log(totalExecucao);
```

Se você executar esse código que coloquei, vai ver que o totalExecução será 820, que é o total de iterações que o ngFor* vai executar no código que você fez.

**Solução**:

Criar um Array temporário, incluir os objetos no array temporário, e depois atribuir o array temporário ao que está sendo utilizado pelo ngFor*.

```
cont: number = 0;
array: number[] = [];
arrayTemp: number[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  let i = 0;

  while(i < 40) {
    this.arrayTemp.push(i);
    i++;
  }
  array = arrayTemp;
}
```